# Google Chrome being blocked by company firewall

Tags: google-chrome, firewall

Yesterday I could use Google Chrome at work to access the internet and today it is being blocked by the firewall with an access denied error. IE and Firefox work fine from the same machine. Is there a way I can easily unblock Chrome so it works again?

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but do your IT dept, have a valid reason for blocking Chrome Specifically?

Comment: What's the point of blocking Chrome ?
If at all, they should block MS Internet Exploder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The blocking is probably being done using the browsers user agent string. You can change the user agent string using the --user-agent command line argument to impersonate IE8, for example use the following.

"C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe" --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"

This of course assumes they are allowing IE8 :-)

However, even if this works, you should check your companies support policies as you may be breaching them.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of places have a proxy server that you have to use to access the internet, if it's site in IE and Firefox but not Chrome, you'd not be able to get online. Check in Firefox's settings to make sure..

Comment: If I remember correctly, Chrome uses the system's proxy settings - the same ones that IE uses.

Comment: I has nothing to do with the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is blocked but you need to use the Webkit engine to test websites, check out the [Iron browser](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php).

Iron is based on the same source code but doesn't transmit information to Google, nor does it automatically update. Those two things may be part of the problem with why Chrome has been blocked. You will still want to run it by your IT department.